# How can I integrate (optional) membership sign-up on a CiviEvent registration form?

Tags: civievent, civimember

I'm creating a paid event that has free/discounted tickets for members. The idea is to encourage visitors to become members when signing up for the event. I feel like this is a common usage scenario, but don't see how this be done without sending people off to a separate membership registration form.

Comment: If you were using Drupal then Commerce and Rules could be used to provide for event rego and memberships in same cart, with the membership discount being applied to the event etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Drupal, and that's an interesting idea, and something I'd never have thought of. However, I'm really not keen on adding such a feature-heavy module as Commerce to do something as "simple" as this. Will save this idea for when I'm really desperate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an extension my colleague built for a client of ours that handles this: https://github.com/aghstrategies/com.aghstrategies.eventmembershipsignup

It should work for you. Unfortunately, we just haven't had the time to get it documented as much as I'd like (or to list it in the extensions directory). If you end up implementing this, please drop me a note at andrew -at- aghstrategies.com. I'd love to hear what suggestions you have, since it is on my to-do list to get it listed and write the documentation needed.

Comment: Awesome, this sounds too good to be true! I'll definitely take a look. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

My company expects to create a new order API by June for 4.7 that will facilitate this, but we don't yet have funding to change pricesets so there is a single type for all three current areas.