# How to renew membership during event registration?

Tags: civievent, civimember, api

I've set-up an event with several fee options that include "event fee plus 1 year membership renewal", "event fee plus 2 years membership renewal", etc. How do you suggest implementing the membership changes after the event payment gets processed?

I'm thinking it's possible to add time to their membership through the ThankYou.php page using the membership API. (using CiviCRM 4.1)

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your CMS?

Comment: Drupal 6. The registration form uses templates - I'm really just not clear about where to program a call to the civimember api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to programm an extension with a hook reacting on the event registration and then changing the membership based on the event registration.

Another way which might be usefull is to use the drupal Webform module and create an event registration with membership options.

Comment: My understanding is that extensions started in CiviCRM 4.2. Maybe this is a good reason to upgrade :)

Answer (score 3):

Browsing through SE today I cam on this question/answer which may also offer a solution:

[How can I integrate (optional) membership sign-up on a CiviEvent registration form?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/603/how-can-i-integrate-optional-membership-sign-up-on-a-civievent-registration-fo)

Summary: a couple of solutions were suggested...

1. If you were using Drupal then Commerce and Rules could be used to provide for event rego and memberships in same cart, with the membership discount being applied to the event etc.
2. There's an extension from AGH Strategies that handles this: https://github.com/aghstrategies/com.aghstrategies.eventmembershipsignup

Comment: Welcome to CiviCRM.SE. It is considered good practice at StackExchange to provide an excerpt or summary of a linked page, as links can go bad— even internal to SE, as questions are sometimes deleted. I encourage you to [edit](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/posts/2462/edit) your post, and to review the [help center](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.